# Warning: [react-router] Location "/index.php?page=login--index" did not match any routes

Tags: php, reactjs, react-router

Here is my url: http://localhost:8888/index.php?page=login--index

I have this error, I don't understand why.

Warning: [react-router] Location "http://localhost:8888/index.php?page=login--index" did not match any routes

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="index.php?page=login--index" component={LoginPage}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Looks like you do not completely understand how the concept of the single page application works. Go through some tutorials about it with the example of react and react-router. Example: https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-react-apps-the-complete-guide

Comment: @Shota I understand the concept but I don't want to use React for single page but only for few components. Can you tell me what is the error here, please?